# Is the centroid of any triangle can be calculated by averaging vertices

Tags: triangles, centroid

Is it always true that the centroid of any triangle can be calculated by averaging the x and y coordinates of its vertices without bothering with finding medians?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: yes, assuming you are finding centroid of vertices or the area.

Comment: Actually, the centroid of  a finite set of points can be calculated that way.

Comment: This is actually true for an arbitrary homogeneous triangle in 3D.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. The centroid  of a finite set of points $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$ has coordinates 
$$\bar x = \frac{1}{n}(x_1+\dots+x_n),\quad \bar y = \frac{1}{n}(y_1+\dots+y_n)$$
Similar in higher dimensions. One can also imagine the points being of unequal masses $m_1,\dots,m_n$; then the center of mass has coordinates
$$\bar x = \frac{1}{M}(m_1x_1+\dots+m_nx_n),\quad \bar y = \frac{1}{M}(m_1y_1+\dots+m_1y_n)$$
where $M=m_1+\dots+m_n$ is the total mass.